# Generic wildcards in return types - how to avoid?

Tags: java, generics, sonarqube

Sonar says

> Generic wildcard types should not be used in return types

Now I have to use an API that accepts an `Iterable<SomeType<?>>` as parameter. How should I create this parameter without violating the Sonar rule if I want to create it in a separate method - so not inline like `List<SomeType<?>> param = new ArrayList();`

Some code I've played around with:

```
interface X<T> {

    }
    static class Blarp {
        void addSomeBlarps(Iterable<X<?>> blub) {
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testGenerics() {
        Blarp b = new Blarp();
        X<?> c = new X<>() {};
        X d = new X() {};
        List<X> blarpList = new ArrayList();
        blarpList.add(c);
        blarpList.add(d);
        List<X<?>> blubList = new ArrayList<>();
        blubList.add(c);
        blubList.add(d);
//        blubList.addAll(blarpList); does not work - why? why can a single X be added but not multiple?
//        blubList.addAll((Collection<? extends X<?>>) blarpList); does seem to work with IntelliJ but then fails on compile

//        b.addSomeBlarps(blarpList); doesn't work - why?
        b.addSomeBlarps(blubList);
    }
```

Comment: Using `X` _anywhere_ without a `<...>` after it can cause weird effects due to how raw types work.  You'll get a warning everywhere you do it, for good reason.

Comment: @LouisWasserman the weird effect in my example occurred *because* the method used the wildcard and not because of any raw types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably there's a misunderstanding.

Let's have a look at

```
public void someMethod(SomeType<?> param) { ... }
```

This method accepts a parameter `param` which has to be of the parameterized type `SomeType` but the method doesn't mind the type parameter (put casually). That is, you can call this method with any parameter of type `SomeType` regardless of the used type parameter.

So, you can create your objects with a concrete type parameter and hand it over to the method, for example

```
public class Test<T> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(newTestString());
        print(newTestLong());
    }

    public static void print(Test<?> someTest) {
        System.out.println(someTest);
    }

    public static Test<String> newTestString() {
        return new Test<String>();
    }

    public static Test<Long> newTestLong() {
        return new Test<Long>();
    }
}
```

**Update**

The misunderstanding was at my side as it's about a generic type of a generic type. That's a different story. In the example the type is an Iterable which is parameterized by `SomeType<?>`. The problem is, that `Iterable<SomeType<String>>` is not a subtype of `Iterable<SomeType<?>>`.

The method would have to accept e. g. a parameter of type `Iterable<? extends SomeType<?>>` to be able to pass a `Iterable<SomeType<String>>`.

As the method is given the way it is, you'll have to work around.

(EDIT: deleted crap I wrote)

I would either not factor out the creation of the object or suppress the warning in that case.

Comment: Could you write a new `newTestIterable` method please so it would fit my example?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood and updated my answer.